# is it OK to use inherit value for ALL non-inherited css properties?

Tags: html, css

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/inherit:

> For non-inherited properties, `inherit` specifies a behavior that
>   typically makes relatively little sense.

I'm wondering what exactly is the page trying to say. So is it telling us that when we do `inherit` for a property which is non-inherited, the behavior is not standardized (may and may not work) ?

Because I've tried `inherit` value for `border` in FF, Chrome, IE, Safari, and Opera and they all work?

is it OK to use inherit value for ALL non-inherited css properties? are they part of the w3c standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it telling us that when we do `inherit` for a property which is non-inherited, the behavior is not standardized (may and may not work) ?

It works as expected in anything but IE < 8, but why would you want to make every property `inherit`? If you specify a border for a parent element `E`, then specify `border: inherit` for `E *`, then **everything** descending from `E` is going to get the same border.

> is it OK to use inherit value for ALL non-inherited css properties?

You can do so for a specific property if you really want an element to inherit that style from its parent, but it doesn't make sense for most designs in general to do it for **every single property**, unless your design is specifically about outlining every single rectangle with a thick red border. As an example, take a look at [this catastrophic mess of a page](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/HVqXB).

> are they part of the w3c standard?

If the spec lists `inherit` as a valid value for that property, whether it's "non-inherited" or not (which means it isn't inherited *by default*), then it's technically supposed to work.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't seem so messy after all if you look at it for a while, but you get what I mean.